# Использование DBMS_SQL в процедуре Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть проблема с использованием `DBMS_SQL`. Есть запрос который читает 4-е столбца. 3-и из них типа `number` и последний `varchar2`. Раньше этого поля не было и процедура нормально работала. Но теперь пришлось добавить и почему то `DBMS_SQL` не пропускает 4-й столбец потому, что даёт ему тип `PLS_INTEGER`.

Как быть в таком случае? Вот код:

```
IF NOT (DBMS_SQL.is_open (ncursor))
          THEN
             ncursor := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;
          END IF;

          DBMS_SQL.parse (ncursor, str_sql, DBMS_SQL.native);

          DBMS_SQL.describe_columns (ncursor, col_cnt, rec_tab);

          FOR colid IN 1 .. col_cnt
          LOOP
             DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN (ncursor, colid, rec_tab (colid).col_type); --, 2000);
          --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_tab(colid).col_name);
          END LOOP;

          sql_result := DBMS_SQL.execute (ncursor);

          WHILE (DBMS_SQL.fetch_rows (ncursor) > 0)
          LOOP
              NULL;
             --ID:=''; SubareasInfoRec.:='';
             DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (ncursor, 1, diameter);
             DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (ncursor, 2, stenka);
             DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (ncursor, 3, shov);
             DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (ncursor, 4, typeCoat);
```

Валиться процедура на строчке `while`. Как раз тогда, когда `fetch_rows` пытается выгрести данные по строкам. Что можно сделать? Как нужно переделать последний параметр в `DEFINE_COLUMNS` так, что бы всё заработало? Я так понимаю в нём дело.
Вот мой запрос:

```
str_sql :=
                 'SELECT mchar.diametr, mchar.stenka, (CASE WHEN (mchar.PROJECTS=''2WELD'') THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) AS welds, regexp_substr(mchar.ND_NAR, ''[^ ]*$'') as ND_NAR';
              str_sql := str_sql || ' FROM TESC4.' || SubareasInfoRec.table_name || ' vt';
              str_sql :=
                 str_sql
                 || ' LEFT JOIN TESC4.PIPE_MAIN_CHARACTERISTICS mchar
                         ON (    vt.god = mchar.god
                             AND vt.truba = mchar.truba
                             AND vt.shop = mchar.shop)
                          WHERE vt.ENTRY_TIME BETWEEN to_date('''
                          || to_char(XTime, 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss') || ''',''dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss'')' ||
                          ' - 5 / 1440 AND  to_date('''
                          || to_char(XTime, 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss') || ''',''dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss'')' ||'
                                AND vt.INST = 1
                                AND EXTRACTVALUE (
                                       vt.description_data,
                                      ''//param[name="ID рабочего центра"]/value'')  IN
                                       (SELECT ID
                                          FROM TESC4.SPR_AGGREGATES
                                         WHERE ID IN (SELECT SHOP_WORKPLACE_UNIT_ID
                                                        FROM SAARC.SPR_SAARC_SHOP_WORKPLACE_UNITS
                                                       WHERE SUBAREA_ID = '
                 || SubareasInfoRec.ID
                 || '))
                           GROUP BY mchar.diametr,
                                    mchar.stenka,
                                    (CASE WHEN (mchar.PROJECTS=''2WELD'') THEN 2 ELSE 1 END),
                                    mchar.ND_NAR';
```

В нём выбирается 4 столбца. И вот как раз их нужно использовать в DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN как это сейчас делается у меня в цикле.

Вот вся процедура:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE       T4_CURRENT_PERFORMANCE_PRC (
    XTime DATE
)
AS
   tmp              CLOB;
   tmpnum           NUMBER (32);
   tmpchar          VARCHAR2 (500);
   Vv_Sql           Varchar2 (1000);
   str_sql          VARCHAR2 (2000);
   sql_str          VARCHAR2 (1200);
   seq_curs_id      NUMBER;
   ncursor          NUMBER;

   sql_result       NUMBER;
   pID               VARCHAR2 (5);
   rID              VARCHAR2 (5);
   table_name       VARCHAR2 (30);
   skip_sw          boolean;
   --num_divider          number;

   rec_tab          DBMS_SQL.desc_tab;

   col_cnt          INTEGER;
   vchtmp           VARCHAR2 (2000);

   diameter         SPR_SAARC_AREA_PERFORMANCE.DIAMETER%TYPE;
   stenka           SPR_SAARC_AREA_PERFORMANCE.THICKNESS%TYPE;
   shov             SPR_SAARC_AREA_PERFORMANCE.WELD_COUNT%TYPE;
   typeCoat         SPR_SAARC_AREA_PERFORMANCE.STANDART_TYPE_COAT%TYPE;
   cnt_hour         SPR_SAARC_AREA_PERFORMANCE.CNT_BY_HOUR%TYPE;

   min_diam         SPR_SAARC_AREA_PERFORMANCE.DIAMETER%TYPE;
   min_stenka       SPR_SAARC_AREA_PERFORMANCE.THICKNESS%TYPE;
   min_shov         SPR_SAARC_AREA_PERFORMANCE.WELD_COUNT%TYPE;
   min_hour         SPR_SAARC_AREA_PERFORMANCE.CNT_BY_HOUR%TYPE;

   cnt_cursor       NUMBER;
   perf_cursor      NUMBER;

   min_row          SPR_SAARC_AREA_PERFORMANCE%ROWTYPE;
   row_cnt          NUMBER;
   EXIST_PERF       NUMBER;
   str_area_id          varchar2(5);
   itmp number;
   dbms_tmp1 varchar2(100);
   dbms_tmp2 number;

   CURSOR GetSubareasInfo is
    SELECT SA.ID, SA.SUBAREA_NAME, SA.AREA_ID,  SA.IS_ACTIVE, SA.SORT_ORDER, SA.PRIORITY, SA.LINE,
       SA.linked_subarea_id, SA.SHOP_WORKCENTRE_ID, MA.AGGREGATE_NAME,MA.TABLE_NAME
    FROM SAARC.SPR_SAARC_SUBAREA SA
    LEFT JOIN SAARC.SPR_SAARC_AREA AR on SA.AREA_ID = AR.ID  
    LEFT JOIN TESC4.SPR_MAINAGGREGAT MA on SA.SHOP_WORKCENTRE_ID = MA.AGGREGATE_ID  
    WHERE AR.SHOP_ID in (301, 141)
      and SA.IS_ACTIVE=1 and SA.SHOP_WORKCENTRE_ID is not null and MA.TABLE_NAME is not null
      and AR.ENABLE_SORTAMENT_CHANGE=1;

   SubareasInfoRec GetSubareasInfo%rowtype; 

   CURSOR perfomances (
      pID      varchar2,
      pdiameter    IN SPR_SAARC_AREA_PERFORMANCE.DIAMETER%TYPE,
      Pstenka   In Spr_Saarc_Area_Performance.Thickness%Type,
      Pshov      In Spr_Saarc_Area_Performance.Weld_Count%Type,
      pType_coat in SPR_SAARC_AREA_PERFORMANCE.STANDART_TYPE_COAT%TYPE
     )
   IS
      SELECT MAX (THICKNESS) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY delta_thick) t,
             MAX (DIAMETER) d,
             MAX (WELD_COUNT) w,
             Max (Coat_Type) c,
             Max (STANDART_TYPE_COAT) s,
             MAX (CNT_BY_HOUR) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY delta_thick)
                CNT_BY_HOUR
        FROM (SELECT PERF.DIAMETER,
                     PERF.THICKNESS,
                     PERF.WELD_COUNT,
                     PERF.STANDART_TYPE_COAT,
                     Perf.Cnt_By_Hour,
                     Perf.Coat_Type,
                     ABS (PERF.THICKNESS - pstenka) delta_thick
                FROM SPR_SAARC_AREA_PERFORMANCE perf
               WHERE     PERF.SUBAREA_ID = pID
                     AND PERF.DIAMETER = pdiameter
                     AND PERF.WELD_COUNT = pshov
                     AND (PERF.STANDART_TYPE_COAT = pType_coat or pType_coat is null));

   perfomance perfomances%rowtype;
   min_perfomance perfomances%rowtype := null;

  cursor CntrRelProstoi(pID varchar2, rID varchar2, pXTime date) is 
    select count(1) cntr from scada_prostoy sp where SP.SUBAREA_ID=pID and SP.EDIT_STATE = 0 and SP.START_DATE < pXTime and
    SP.START_DATE >=  (select max(SP2.END_DATE) from scada_prostoy SP2  where  SP2.SUBAREA_ID=rID and SP2.EDIT_STATE = 0 and SP2.END_DATE < pXTime);
    --select count(1) cntr from scada_prostoy sp where SP.REC_DATE BETWEEN pXTime - 5 / 1440 and pXTime and
    --      SP.SUBAREA_ID=pID and SP.EDIT_STATE = 0 and SP.START_DATE >= 
    --        (select max(SP2.END_DATE) from scada_prostoy SP2  where  SP2.SUBAREA_ID=rID and SP2.EDIT_STATE = 0);
  CntrRelProstoiRec CntrRelProstoi%rowtype;
  fCntrRelProstoiSuccess boolean;

BEGIN

    --INSERT INTO LOG_INTERFACE_ERRORS (PROCEDURE_NAME, ERROR_MESSAGE) 
    --            VALUES ('T4_CURRENT_PERFORMANCE_PRC', 'Вызов процедуры T4_CURRENT_PERFORMANCE_PRC');

   open GetSubareasInfo;
   LOOP
      FETCH GetSubareasInfo INTO SubareasInfoRec;
      EXIT WHEN GetSubareasInfo%NOTFOUND;
      min_perfomance := null; skip_sw := false;

      if (SubareasInfoRec.linked_subarea_id is not null) then -- если указан код связанного подучастка

        open CntrRelProstoi(SubareasInfoRec.linked_subarea_id, SubareasInfoRec.ID, XTime);
        fetch CntrRelProstoi into CntrRelProstoiRec;
        fCntrRelProstoiSuccess := CntrRelProstoi%notfound;
        close CntrRelProstoi;

        if (fCntrRelProstoiSuccess) then
            if( CntrRelProstoiRec.CNTR > 0) then                      -- если агрегат был отключен,
               select count(1) into itmp from CURRENT_SUBAREA_PERFORMANCE 
               where SUBAREA_ID = SubareasInfoRec.ID and cnt_by_hour = -1  and insert_time = 
               (select max(c2.insert_time) from CURRENT_SUBAREA_PERFORMANCE c2 where c2.SUBAREA_ID = SubareasInfoRec.ID 
               and c2.insert_time < XTime);

               if (itmp = 0) then
                insert into CURRENT_SUBAREA_PERFORMANCE (SUBAREA_ID, cnt_by_hour, insert_time)
                values (SubareasInfoRec.ID, -1, XTime);
               end if;               
               skip_sw := true;
            end if;
        end if;      
      end if;      

      if not skip_sw then
          -- Получение сортаментов на агрегатах подучастка
          if(SubareasInfoRec.AREA_ID = 142 or SubareasInfoRec.AREA_ID = 143 or SubareasInfoRec.AREA_ID = 681 or SubareasInfoRec.AREA_ID = 682) then
              str_sql :=
                 'SELECT mchar.diametr, mchar.stenka, (CASE WHEN (mchar.PROJECTS=''2WELD'') THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) AS welds, regexp_substr(mchar.ND_NAR, ''[^ ]*$'') as ND_NAR';
              str_sql := str_sql || ' FROM TESC4.' || SubareasInfoRec.table_name || ' vt';
              str_sql :=
                 str_sql
                 || ' LEFT JOIN TESC4.PIPE_MAIN_CHARACTERISTICS mchar
                         ON (    vt.god = mchar.god
                             AND vt.truba = mchar.truba
                             AND vt.shop = mchar.shop)
                          WHERE vt.ENTRY_TIME BETWEEN to_date('''
                          || to_char(XTime, 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss') || ''',''dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss'')' ||
                          ' - 5 / 1440 AND  to_date('''
                          || to_char(XTime, 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss') || ''',''dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss'')' ||'
                                AND vt.INST = 1
                                AND EXTRACTVALUE (
                                       vt.description_data,
                                      ''//param[name="ID рабочего центра"]/value'')  IN
                                       (SELECT ID
                                          FROM TESC4.SPR_AGGREGATES
                                         WHERE ID IN (SELECT SHOP_WORKPLACE_UNIT_ID
                                                        FROM SAARC.SPR_SAARC_SHOP_WORKPLACE_UNITS
                                                       WHERE SUBAREA_ID = '
                 || SubareasInfoRec.ID
                 || '))
                           GROUP BY mchar.diametr,
                                    mchar.stenka,
                                    (CASE WHEN (mchar.PROJECTS=''2WELD'') THEN 2 ELSE 1 END),
                                    mchar.ND_NAR';
          else
              str_sql :=
                 'SELECT mchar.diametr, mchar.stenka, (CASE WHEN (mchar.PROJECTS=''2WELD'') THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) AS welds';
              str_sql := str_sql || ' FROM TESC4.' || SubareasInfoRec.table_name || ' vt';
              str_sql :=
                 str_sql
                 || ' LEFT JOIN TESC4.PIPE_MAIN_CHARACTERISTICS mchar
                         ON (    vt.god = mchar.god
                             AND vt.truba = mchar.truba
                             AND vt.shop = mchar.shop)
                          WHERE vt.ENTRY_TIME BETWEEN to_date('''
                          || to_char(XTime, 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss') || ''',''dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss'')' ||
                          ' - 5 / 1440 AND  to_date('''
                          || to_char(XTime, 'dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss') || ''',''dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss'')' ||'
                                AND vt.INST = 1
                                AND EXTRACTVALUE (
                                       vt.description_data,
                                      ''//param[name="ID рабочего центра"]/value'')  IN
                                       (SELECT ID
                                          FROM TESC4.SPR_AGGREGATES
                                         WHERE ID IN (SELECT SHOP_WORKPLACE_UNIT_ID
                                                        FROM SAARC.SPR_SAARC_SHOP_WORKPLACE_UNITS
                                                       WHERE SUBAREA_ID = '
                 || SubareasInfoRec.ID
                 || '))
                           GROUP BY mchar.diametr,
                                    mchar.stenka,
                                    (CASE WHEN (mchar.PROJECTS=''2WELD'') THEN 2 ELSE 1 END)';
          end if;

          IF NOT (DBMS_SQL.is_open (ncursor))
          THEN
             ncursor := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;
          END IF;

          DBMS_SQL.parse (ncursor, str_sql, DBMS_SQL.native);

          DBMS_SQL.describe_columns (ncursor, col_cnt, rec_tab);

          FOR colid IN 1 .. col_cnt
          LOOP
             if(rec_tab (colid).col_type = 2) then
                DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN (ncursor, colid, dbms_tmp2);
             elsif(rec_tab (colid).col_type = 1) then
                DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN (ncursor, colid, dbms_tmp1, 100);
             end if;
          --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_tab(colid).col_name);
          END LOOP;       

          sql_result := DBMS_SQL.execute (ncursor);

          WHILE (DBMS_SQL.fetch_rows (ncursor) > 0)
          LOOP
              NULL;
             --ID:=''; SubareasInfoRec.:='';
             DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (ncursor, 1, diameter);
             DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (ncursor, 2, stenka);
             DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (ncursor, 3, shov);
             DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (ncursor, 4, typeCoat);

             IF (diameter IS NOT NULL AND stenka IS NOT NULL AND shov IS NOT NULL)
             THEN
                if(SubareasInfoRec.AREA_ID <> 142 and SubareasInfoRec.AREA_ID <> 143 and SubareasInfoRec.AREA_ID <> 681 and SubareasInfoRec.AREA_ID <> 682) then
                    typeCoat := null;
                end if;
                OPEN perfomances (SubareasInfoRec.ID,
                                  diameter,
                                  stenka,
                                  shov,
                                  typeCoat);

                LOOP
                   FETCH perfomances INTO perfomance;
                   EXIT WHEN perfomances%NOTFOUND;
                       IF (min_perfomance.d IS NULL
                           OR min_perfomance.CNT_BY_HOUR > perfomance.CNT_BY_HOUR)
                       THEN
                          --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (perfomance.CNT_BY_HOUR);
                          min_perfomance := perfomance;
                       END IF;
                END LOOP;

                CLOSE perfomances;
             END IF;
          END LOOP;

          DBMS_SQL.close_cursor (ncursor);

          --num_divider:=0;
          /*
          select divider into num_divider from (select ID,  
            case when count(1) over(partition by SORT_ORDER) =0 then 1 
            else count(1) over(partition by SORT_ORDER) end DIVIDER
            from SPR_SAARC_SUBAREA where area_id=SubareasInfoRec.AREA_ID) where ID=SubareasInfoRec.ID;
          */

          IF ( min_perfomance.CNT_BY_HOUR IS NOT NULL
              AND min_perfomance.CNT_BY_HOUR > 0)
              --AND num_divider IS NOT NULL
              --AND num_divider > 0)
          THEN

             EXIST_PERF := 0;

             SELECT COUNT (1)
               INTO EXIST_PERF
               FROM CURRENT_SUBAREA_PERFORMANCE
              WHERE     subarea_id = SubareasInfoRec.ID
                    AND diameter = min_perfomance.d
                    AND cnt_by_hour = min_perfomance.CNT_BY_HOUR -- / num_divider
                    AND thickness = min_perfomance.t
                    AND (typeCoat = min_perfomance.s or typeCoat is null)
                    And Weld_Count = Min_Perfomance.W
                    AND insert_time =
                           (SELECT MAX (insert_time) mit
                              FROM CURRENT_SUBAREA_PERFORMANCE sp
                             WHERE  subarea_id = SubareasInfoRec.ID 
                             and insert_time <= XTime);

             IF EXIST_PERF = 0
             THEN
                /*
                SELECT *
                  INTO cur_row
                  FROM SPR_SAARC_AREA_PERFORMANCE
                 WHERE     subarea_id = SubareasInfoRec.ID
                       AND diameter = min_perfomance.d
                       AND thickness = min_perfomance.t
                       AND weld_count = min_perfomance.w;
                 */
                 if(SubareasInfoRec.AREA_ID <> 142 and SubareasInfoRec.AREA_ID <> 143 and SubareasInfoRec.AREA_ID <> 681 and SubareasInfoRec.AREA_ID <> 682) then
                    min_perfomance.s := null;
                 end if;
                      Insert Into CURRENT_SUBAREA_PERFORMANCE (
                         Subarea_Id, Diameter, STANDART_TYPE_COAT, Thickness,
                         Coat_Type, Weld_Count, Cnt_By_Hour, 
                         INSERT_TIME, Is_Automatic)
                      VALUES ( SubareasInfoRec.ID,
                         min_perfomance.d,
                         min_perfomance.s,
                         Min_Perfomance.T,
                         min_perfomance.c,
                         min_perfomance.w,
                         --min_perfomance.CNT_BY_HOUR / num_divider,
                         Min_Perfomance.Cnt_By_Hour,
                         XTime, 1);

             END IF;

         End If;

         Min_Perfomance := Null;

      end if; --

   END LOOP;

   close GetSubareasInfo;

   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      Tmp := 'ошибка: ' || Sqlcode || ' ' || Sqlerrm;
      insert into Perf_Log (Error_Text) Values (Tmp); commit;
 /*  WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      tmp := 'ошибка: ' || SQLCODE || ' ' || SQLERRM;
      Insert Into Perf_Log (Error_Text) Values (Tmp); Commit; */
      RAISE;
END T4_CURRENT_PERFORMANCE_PRC;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваша проблема в этой строчке:

```
DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN (ncursor, colid, rec_tab (colid).col_type); --, 2000);
```

В `rec_tab (colid).col_type` после `describe_columns` содержится численное представление типа полей, как то `varchar2 -> 1`, `number -> 2`, `date -> 12` и т.д..

Функция `define_column` перегружена для всех основных типов и ожидает действительно переменную того типа, который будет в `fetch_rows`, а не `rec_tab (colid).col_type`, тип которой `binary_integer`. Здесь важен именно тип, можно использовать ту же переменную, которая будет в последствии использоватся в `column_value`, но это не обязательно. Функция `describe_columns` и определение `rec_tab` больше не используются.

Процедура будет выглядеть где-то так:

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited  
<your_procedure> declare 
    ncursor integer; 
    sql_result integer;
    diameter number;
    stenka number;
    shov number;
    typeCoat varchar2(1999);
    str_sql varchar2(32676) := q'[
        select 111 diameter, 222 stenka, 0 shov, cast('typeCoat blah blah' as varchar2(1999)) typeCoat from dual
    ]';
begin
    ncursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse (ncursor, str_sql, dbms_sql.native);
    dbms_sql.define_column (ncursor, 1, diameter);
    dbms_sql.define_column (ncursor, 2, stenka);
    dbms_sql.define_column (ncursor, 3, shov);
    dbms_sql.define_column (ncursor, 4, typeCoat, 1999);
    sql_result := DBMS_SQL.execute (ncursor);
    while (DBMS_SQL.fetch_rows (ncursor) > 0) loop
        dbms_sql.column_value (ncursor, 1, diameter);
        dbms_sql.column_value (ncursor, 2, stenka);
        dbms_sql.column_value (ncursor, 3, shov);
        dbms_sql.column_value (ncursor, 4, typecoat);
        dbms_output.put_line('processing_data: diameter/stenka/shov='||diameter||'/'||stenka||'/'||shov||'/'||typeCoat); 
    end loop;
end your_procedure;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

processing_data: diameter/stenka/shov=111/222/0/typeCoat blah blah
```

Оракловая [документация](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21645/d_sql.htm#TTPLP71250) не всегда лучший истоник, но основное там описано.

**Второй подход к решению**

Обдумайте ещё раз дизайн: `DBMS_SQL` нужен только тогда, когда действительно запрос динамический, т.е. ни колличество полей, ни их тип, заранее не известен. Если это не тот случай, то `DBMS_SQL` совершенно излишен. В вашем случае:

```
set server output on size unlimited
<<processing_data>> declare 
    str_sql varchar2(32676) := 'select ... my query ...';
    type mycursor is ref cursor;
    diameter number;
    stenka number;
    shov number;
    typeCoat varchar2(1999);
begin
    open mycursor for str_sql;
    loop fetch mycursor into diameter, stenka, shov, typeCoat;
        exit when mycursor%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line('processing_data: diameter/stenka/shov='||
            diameter||'/'||stenka||'/'||shov||'/'||typeCoat); 
    end loop; 
    close mycursor;
end processing_data;
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64525/discussion-between-0xdb-and-).