# Функция динамического создания Excel файла для любой таблицы

Tags: sql, oracle, excel, csv, plsql

Делаю функцию, которая создаёт динамически Excel файл. Однако есть загвоздка, а именно, файл должен выглядеть вот так:

[image: План]

а выглядит вот так :

[image: Факт]

Всё заполняется данными из колонки `id` (поскольку `rec_tab(i).id`). Не получается динамически изменить имя колонки коллекции в части кода, которую я укажу ниже. Понятное дело, что если я руками укажу колонка `FIO` (`rec_tab(i).FIO`) в той части кода, где мне нужна помощь, то все поля заполнятся как `Surname1-6`.

Хочется добавлять разные таблицы с разным количеством столбцов и чтобы именно в этой части кода не надо было указывать имя поля. Конкатенация здесь не работает, т.к. неверный синтксис -  `rec_tab(i).||v_headers`.

Код:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_xls_from_table
  RETURN BLOB is
    ---
    TYPE            headers_type IS REF CURSOR; 
    cur             headers_type;
    headers         VARCHAR2(69);
    tab_col_count   NUMBER;    
    ---
    TYPE            data is REF CURSOR;
    tab             data;
    TYPE            t_table is TABLE of ИМЯ_ТАБЛИЦЫ%ROWTYPE;
    rec_tab         t_table;
    ---
    vFileBody       BLOB;
    col_num         INTEGER := 0;
    v_headers       VARCHAR2(69);  
BEGIN
  as_xlsx.clear_workbook;
  as_xlsx.new_sheet('Search');  
  -------------
  OPEN cur FOR 'SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = upper(ИМЯ_ТАБЛИЦЫ)';   
     LOOP
      FETCH cur INTO headers;
      EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
       -- headers
      col_num := col_num + 1;
      as_xlsx.set_row(1, p_fontId => as_xlsx.get_font('Times New Roman', p_fontsize => 10, p_bold => true),
      p_fillId => as_xlsx.get_fill('solid', 'FFCC66'), p_borderId => as_xlsx.get_border);
      -- header columns
      as_xlsx.set_column_width(col_num, 14);
      as_xlsx.cell(col_num, 1, headers, p_alignment => as_xlsx.get_alignment
      (p_horizontal => 'center', p_vertical => 'center', p_wraptext => true));
     
     tab_col_count := cur%rowcount;
  -------------
  OPEN tab FOR 'SELECT * FROM '|| tab_name ||' ORDER BY 1';
   FETCH tab BULK COLLECT INTO rec_tab limit 6;   
   
   v_headers := headers;
   
   FOR i IN rec_tab.first .. rec_tab.last
    LOOP
    -- cell
    as_xlsx.set_row(i + 1, p_fontId => as_xlsx.get_font('Times New Roman', p_fontsize => 9), p_borderId => as_xlsx.get_border);

    FOR x in 1 .. tab_col_count
      LOOP


        as_xlsx.cell(x, i + 1, rec_tab(i).id, -- <<<<<<-------- КАК ЭТО ПРАВИЛЬНО ЗАМЕНИТЬ?


        p_alignment => as_xlsx.get_alignment(p_horizontal => 'center', p_vertical => 'center', p_wraptext => true));
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE tab; 
  -------------  
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur;
  
  vFileBody:=as_xlsx.finish;
  RETURN vFileBody;
END;
```

Comment: А почему  вы не используете dbms_sql, а изобретате что-то новое? `ИМЯ_ТАБЛИЦЫ%ROWTYPE;` это статическя структура, вы не сможете её использовать в контексте вашей задачи. Если вы используете в коде сторонние библиотеки, которые к вопросу не относятся, то создавайте минимальный пример без этих библиотек. Версию укажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Версия Oracle - 11g

Comment: То есть, вы поняли как решить задачу?

Comment: Я понял, что надо изучить библиотеку DBMS_SQL.. поэтому пока не понял

Comment: Посмотрите поиском: [oracle] DBMS_SQL. Там немного и примеры вроде понятные. Начните писать под себя пока без as_xlsx. Напишиете, если возникнут  трудности.

Comment: Я боюсь, что крыша поедет..))

Comment: Почему поедет? Начните с небольшого примера, который выведет простейший  CSV из двух-трёх колонок и двух строчек. Kогда он станет понятен, усложняйте его шаг за шагом. Крыша встанет на место. Попробую сегодня вам такой пример накидать.

Comment: Спасибо! Если покажете - буду признателен.. сам себе задачу выдумал, 2 дня мучаюсь.. сил нет) а тут оказывается есть пакет нужный.. ну.. это и хорошо.. так и учимся!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Простой рабочий пример для задачи как в вопросе (остаётся только встроить `AS_XLSX`):

```
create or replace procedure printCsv (what varchar2, sep char := ',') is
    nc number; 
    rc number;
    ncol number;
    headers varchar2 (32767); 
    cols dbms_sql.desc_tab;
    colvalue varchar2 (64);
    colvalues varchar2 (32767);
begin
    nc := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse (nc, what, dbms_sql.native);
    dbms_sql.describe_columns (nc, ncol, cols);
    for ix in 1..ncol loop
        dbms_sql.define_column(nc, ix, colvalue, 64);
        headers := headers||cols(ix).col_name||sep; 
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line (rtrim (headers, sep));
    rc := dbms_sql.execute (nc);
    while dbms_sql.fetch_rows (nc) > 0 loop
        colvalues := null; 
        for ix  in 1..ncol loop
            dbms_sql.column_value (nc, ix, colvalue);
            colvalues := colvalues||colvalue||sep;
        end loop;
        dbms_output.put_line (rtrim (colvalues, sep));
    end loop;
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(nc);
end printCsv;
/
```

Пример вызова и вывод результата:

```
exec printCSV (q'[-
    select employee_id,first_name,last_name, hire_date, job_id,department_id -
    from hr.employees ]')

EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID
100,Steven,King,2003-06-17 00:00:00,AD_PRES,90
101,Neena,Kochhar,2005-09-21 00:00:00,AD_VP,90
102,Lex,De Haan,2001-01-13 00:00:00,AD_VP,90
[...]
```

---

PS В примере для упрощения использовано неявное преобразование типов данных всех колонок в символьный - `colvalue` . См. [пример с учётом типа данных колонок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710278), если неявное преобразование нежелательно.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Изучу dbms_sql обязательно!

Comment: Рад был помочь! А зачем изучать dbms_sql? Вставляйте в нужные места вызовы   as_xlsx, пол-часа и всё готово.

Comment: а что? неактуальный пакет? в будущем не пригодится?

Comment: Почему, актуальный. Если вы поняли как этот пример работает, то изучать пока ничего не надо, остальное детали. Главное понять, когда его применять. Если в rec_tab(i).<имя поля> заранее неизвестно, то динамический SQL, в любом другом случае - статический.

Comment: Привет! Спасибо, всё получилось. А подойдёт ли dbms_sql для случая когда передаётся коллекция, а не селект? И почему-то ограничение вывода в эксель 32767 символов..

Comment: Не совсем понял, какая коллекция и какое это имеет отношение к dbms_sql?

Comment: Есть тип таблицы TYPE t_tbl is TABLE OF tab_name%ROWTYPE. Есть переменная v_tbl t_tbl - она заполняется данными селекта. Делаем эксель-файл v_file:=GetXlsFile(v_tbl). Подойдёт ли вышеуказанный Вами код для формирования файла из v_tbl? Чтобы сигнатура вызываемой функции была такая.. function GetXlsFile(p_tab in t_tab) return blob is

Comment: А зачем  тогда dbms_sql? Раз вы tab_name%ROWTYPE передаёте, то это значит, что таблица известна, её колонки тоже, динамический SQL не нужен.

Comment: Суть в том, что это сейчас мы знаем таблицу. А если будет другая таблица? Динамика в создании экселя для типа любой таблицы, которую функция заранее не знает.

Comment: Помоему вы повторяете свой вопрос. Если имя таблицы известно, то статика, если нет - динамика.  Насчёт ограничений на 32767 - не знаю, blob того ограничения не имеет, это макс. длина varchar. Какую библиотеку as_xlsx вы используете, от Антона или газпрома?

Comment: Понял, логично.. от Антона.. от Газпрома она как от Антона или совсем другая?

Comment: От Газпрома это форк от Антона, какие-то расширения они туда прикрутили.

Comment: Её в свободном доступе не нашёл..Ладно, спасибо Вам, не в первый раз уже помогаете!

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с версии 18c можно воспользоваться PTF [(*Polymorphic Table Functions*)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-981102A8-5204-4931-B10A-93486304B184).

Объединить все строки в одну с колонками соддержащими общую информацию и сам документ. Как параметр эта функция может принять любой набор данных: таблицу, CTE, представление и т.д.

Например:

```
with docdata ("Id", "Name", "Created") as (
    select rownum, 'Name '||rownum, to_char (sysdate+rownum/24, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
    from dual connect by level<=3)
select * from docpkg.getХls (docdata)
/
MEMO                                     XLSX
---------------------------------------- ----------------
Converted 3 rows. Docsize 5840 bytes.    504B030414000000
                                         08001B9FED508673
```

Открыв колонку `XLSX` в Excel, можно увидеть такой результат:

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реализация функции (использован [внешний пакет as_xlsx](https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/as_xlsx18.txt)):

```
create or replace package docpkg as
    function describe (tab in out dbms_tf.table_t) return dbms_tf.describe_t;
    procedure open;
    procedure fetch_rows;
    procedure close;
    function getXls (t table) return table pipelined table polymorphic using docpkg;   
end docpkg;
/
create or replace package body docpkg as
    rs dbms_tf.row_set_t;
    rowcnt number;
    total number;
    
    function describe (tab in out dbms_tf.table_t) return dbms_tf.describe_t as
    begin
        for ix in 1..tab.column.count () loop
            tab.column(ix).pass_through := false; 
            tab.column(ix).for_read := true; end loop;
        return dbms_tf.describe_t (
            dbms_tf.columns_new_t (
                1=>dbms_tf.column_metadata_t (name=>'memo', type=>dbms_tf.type_varchar2),
                2=>dbms_tf.column_metadata_t (name=>'xlsx', type=>dbms_tf.type_blob)), 
            row_replication=>true);
    end;
    procedure open is
        cols dbms_tf.table_metadata_t := dbms_tf.get_env ().get_columns;
    begin 
        as_xlsx.clear_workbook;
        as_xlsx.new_sheet ('Sheet 1');  
        as_xlsx.set_row (
            1, p_fontId=>as_xlsx.get_font ('Arial', p_fontsize=>10, p_bold => true),
            p_fillId => as_xlsx.get_fill ('solid', 'FFCC66'), p_borderId=>as_xlsx.get_border);
        for cn in 1..cols.count loop
            dbms_tf.trace(cols(cn).name); 
            as_xlsx.set_column_width (cn, 16);
            as_xlsx.cell (cn, 1, trim (both '"' from cols(cn).name), p_alignment=>as_xlsx.get_alignment (
                p_horizontal=>'center', p_vertical=>'center', p_wraptext=>true));
        end loop;    
        dbms_tf.xstore_set ('total', 0);
    end open;
    procedure fetch_rows as
        colcnt pls_integer;
        rn number;
    begin
        dbms_tf.get_row_set (rs, rowcnt, colcnt); 
        dbms_tf.xstore_get ('total', total);
        for rid in 1..rowcnt loop
            rn := total+rid+1;
            as_xlsx.set_row (
                rn, p_fontId=>as_xlsx.get_font ('Consolas', p_fontsize => 10), p_borderId=>as_xlsx.get_border);
            for cn in 1..colcnt loop
                as_xlsx.cell (cn, rn, dbms_tf.col_to_char (rs(cn), rid, null), p_alignment=>as_xlsx.get_alignment (
                    p_horizontal => 'center', p_vertical => 'center', p_wraptext => true));
            end loop; 
        end loop; 
        total := total + rowcnt;
        dbms_tf.xstore_set ('total', total);
        dbms_tf.put_row_set (rs, 0);
        return;
    end;
    procedure close is
        rf dbms_tf.tab_naturaln_t;    
        doc blob;
    begin
        dbms_tf.get_row_set (rs, rowcnt);   
        dbms_tf.xstore_get ('total', total);
        rf (1) := 1;
        for i in 2..rowcnt loop rf (i) := 0; end loop;
        doc := as_xlsx.finish; 
        rs(1).tab_varchar2 (1) := 'Converted '||total||' rows. Docsize '||length (doc)||' bytes.'; 
        rs(2).tab_blob (1) := doc;
        dbms_tf.put_row_set (rs, rf);   
        return;
    end;
end docpkg;
/
```

Comment: Пакет не компилируется, ругается на function getXls (t table) return table pipelined table polymorphic using docpkg; "Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TABLE" when expecting one of the following:
                 in out <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
          ... long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary
          national character nchar
Line: 6
"

Comment: @mrprogre Первые три слова в ответе: _Начиная с версии 18c_. А вы в какой компилируете?

Comment: В версии 11.. но я не русский мужик, если ж не попробую! да ещё и пару раз!!

Comment: @mrprogre Это то, что в будущем возможно заменит dbms_sql, во всяком случае дизайнеры Oracle стремятся к этому. Поставте на какой-нибудь тестовой машине актуальную версию и пробуйте, хоть три раза ))

Comment: Спасибо за труд!! Просто всего лишь второй год пошёл как я в pl/sql, вот и пробую всё подряд.. а в будущем я уверен, что упростят ещё сильнее :)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант у вас динамический запрос, можете его сформировать по типу

Select id as col1, .. , code as col10, ... From table

В данном варианте у вас всегда на внутреннем запросе стилизованные поля.

Comment: так это уже не динамическое получается.. неужели нет способа изменить имя поля, чтобы не прописывать конкретно столбцы?

Comment: Динамический запрос тогда полностью